# UICollectionView only showing 2 sets of data

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have UICollectionView embedded inside another UICollectionView (as a kind of table.) The first collection view works fine - I get the correct number of cells and the correct information in them. The second one however I only ever get the first 2 sets of data displayed. Here is the code for the cellForItemAtIndexPath for the outer collection view:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Main Tide Data Table Cell";

    TideDataTableCell* tideDayDataCell = [self.tideDataTable dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tidalDate* tideDate = self.tidalDates[indexPath.row];
    tideDayDataCell.tides = nil;
    tideDayDataCell.tides = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    tideDayDataCell.tideDataTable.delegate = tideDayDataCell;
    tideDayDataCell.tideDataTable.dataSource = tideDayDataCell;
    self.tideDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    tideDayDataCell.tides = tideDate.tides;
    tideDayDataCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tideDayDataCell.dayLabel.text = tideDate.dateString;
    tideDayDataCell.averageTideHeight = self.avgTideHeight;
    return tideDayDataCell;
}
```

And here is the cellForItemAtIndexPath for the inner collection view that doesn't work properly - repeating the first 2 sets of data...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Tide Info Table Cell";

    TidalTideTableCell* tidalTideTableCell = [self.tideDataTable dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tidalTideTableCell.timeTideLabel.text = @"";
    tidalTideTableCell.heightTideLabel.text = @"";
    tidalTideTableCell.hwlwTideLabel.text = @"";
    self.tideDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Tide* tide = self.tides[indexPath.row];
    tidalTideTableCell.heightTideLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tide.height] stringValue];
    if (tide.height > self.averageTideHeight)
    {
        tidalTideTableCell.hwlwTideLabel.text = @"HW";
    }
    else
    {
        tidalTideTableCell.hwlwTideLabel.text = @"LW";
    }
    tidalTideTableCell.timeTideLabel.text = tide.date;
    tidalTideTableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return tidalTideTableCell;
}
```

As you can hopefully see - the array that holds the information (tides) is initiallized every time this is called, and I have checked that the data being fed in is correct as far as I can.
I would be grateful for any help...

Comment: I don;t know whether this will help - basically the first "outside" collection view has one cell for each of seven days, the embedded collection contain 3 or 4 cells of data.

Comment: The second cellForItemAtIndexPath function above is called for the first 2 outside tables - and never again after that...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are sending wrong number of sections / rows. I hope you have solved your problem in the meantime.